# Function result undefined when accessed within another function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get back the result of a function inside another one but always getting undefined:

```
$(window).load(function() {

   var isMobile = false;
      function check_OS() {

        if (/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          isMobile = true;
        }
      }

     check_OS();


$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeImage();
});


function resizeImage() {
        console.log(isMobile)
}

});
```

the result of isMobile within that function resizeImage() is always undefined and I don't know why :(.

can be seen here:

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/responsive-template/test/

Comment: Move function declaration and isMobile variable out of window.load. And try to avoid raw resize function cause when You have more onResize events it will lag your page when someone will resize the window of a browser dragging it with mouse. Use delayed resize. Also use on('resize') / on('load').

Comment: Because `var isMobile = false;` is defined in another scope, so it's not available where you are trying to access it. Your code in question is not the same as in demo.

Comment: That's how javascript works. isMobile is only accessible from with the $(window).load function() {}.

You might want to read more about j[avascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: move ` var isMobile = false;` to above `$(window).load(function() {})`

Comment: simple jsfiddle would be really helpful to debug and help

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6jL64ave/2/
move those elements:

```
var isMobile = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeImage();
        console.log('wow')
});
function resizeImage() {
        console.log(isMobile)
        console.log('wow')
}
```

outside window load function